# Histogram with "PDF" option with strange values on y-axis - Interpretation?

Tags: histograms

Here's a working example of what I see:

```
 data={0.6999999999999999556, 0.6996988902611553518, 
    0.69822065610479532940, 0.69765711258500941073, 
    0.69765711258500941073, 0.69765711258500941073, 
    0.69726059945300671882, 0.69726059945300671882, 
    0.69863796227970390289, 0.7007574121003866296}

Histogram[data, {0.001}, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "\[Beta]", 
 GridLines -> {{{mean, Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Blue]}}, None}, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

and here's the picture the above code produces:

[image]

From a question in this forum, I know that if I use the option "Probability", I'll get the histogram I want.

However, I wonder how does one interpret the values on the y-axis in the case of "PDF"? In my histogram above, I get strange values of 200, 300, 400, 500. How do I interpret them?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely get a more in-depth answer at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but here's a short answer:

**For your particular histogram:**  The area of the bars in a histogram sum to 1 when you use the `PDF` option. That's all there is to it. Your vertical scale is "large" because your "horizontal" scale is so small. Just multiply the heights by the width of the bars and add them up:  500*0.001 + 200*0.001 + 100*0.001 + 200*0.001 = 1.

**Histograms in general:**  If you just have a single histogram (hopefully with a lot more than 10 sample points), then it probably doesn't matter what scaling you use ("PDF","Probability", "Count", etc.) as you'll get the same shape.

It will matter how you scale if you want to compare visually more than one histogram.

Here's what you get from from two random samples using "Probability":

```
SeedRandom[12345];
x1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
x2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 200];
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[x1, Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 0.35}}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium],
  Histogram[x2, Automatic, "Probability",  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 0.35}}]}]
```

[image: Two histograms with probability scaling]

With `"Probability"` scaling the sum of the heights of the bars sums to 1 but even plotted with same horizontal and vertical scales one can't make an appropriate assessment of the differences.

But if you use a `"PDF"` scaling you can compare the histograms:

```
GraphicsRow[{Histogram[x1, Automatic, "PDF", 
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> Medium],
  Histogram[x2, Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 1.5}}]}]
```

[image: Two histograms with PDF scaling]

Here the sum of the areas of the bars sum to 1 and one can then make reasonable comparisons of the spread of the data as this also accounts for the differences in sample size.

Another reason for choosing `"PDF"` scaling is that it is many times the probability density function (from which you took samples) is the entity that you're trying to estimate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer JimB. I understand your answer, but I was asking specifically about the values in my histogram... I get some strange 200, 300, 500... How would I explain to someone what they are? It's a different scale, but which one?

Comment: To repeat:  the area of the bars in your histogram sum to 1 when you use the `PDF` options.  That's all there is to it.  The vertical scale is "large" because your "horizontal" scale is so small.  500*0.001 + 200*0.001 + 100*0.001 + 200*0.001 = 1.

Comment: Jim, thanks for that comment. :) Include it in your answer, and I'll accept it. ;)

Comment: Your edit was correct but I decided to move it to the top of the answer and expand a little bit.  Thanks.